# Unix crypt() function in smalltalk/pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I want to encode passwords for UNIX accounts using the [crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29) function. I'm using pharo 1.0. I tried to install the crypto package from squeakmap, but it gaves me an error and the package seem to get partially installed (categories without class).

How can I get my password crypted? I'm willing to invoke external code, if it is required (and there's a package in SqueakMap that makes the trick in pharo).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look if you have a category System-Digital Signatures in your image, with a class SecureHashAlgorithm. You can then hash your password as follows:

```
(SecureHashAlgorithm new hashMessage: 'my password') asString
```

Comment: Thanks!

In fact, I do have that class. It gives me:

    (SecureHashAlgorithm new hashMessage: 'my password') asString.
    '930408691521612642154581053007002882786966762294'

But, I need the hashed password for unix accounts, so they must be in one of the traditional crypt formats:

    {crypt}0R9nvENe5JUlE
    {crypt}$1$8xbtm8Xw$G4HYuFl2fPRUgUBge26CN/

Is there a method for this?

Thanks again.

Comment: Above class uses SHA hash algorithm. Which algorithm uses crypt these days? 
Another possibility would be to call some external program with appropriate parameters, using OSProcess class.

Answer (score 3):

In Pharo check the category: System-Hashing.

There you have MD5 and SHA.

Classes: SHA1, MD5NonPrimitive, MD5.

Those classes were extracted from the crypto package from squeaksource, and make them work in Pharo. Then MD5 and SHA were integrated in the core.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is the PasswordHashingFFI package in the Cryptography repository that uses FFI to access the crypt(3) library on linux.

Its here:

http://www.squeaksource.com/Cryptography.html

Use is like

```
CryptLinuxFFI sha256:'1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

OSProcess can be used to call any external program. Have a look at http://book.pharo-project.org/book/PharoTools/OSProcess/